# Secure file management with symfony

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony1, download

By default, symfony uploades file to web/upload folder, so they are accessible for anyone. I need to check user credentials on every request to a file. How should I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Move your uploads outside of your webroot, like in /data/uploads. In that case, you'll need to put this in your ProjectConfiguration file:

```
sfConfig::set('sf_upload_dir' => sfConfig::get("sf_data_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads');
```

Provided that you always used sf_upload_dir to specify the uploads folder, all your files will get saved there.

The second part of the solution needs a new action, that gets a filename, checks if the user has access to it, and returns:

- either a 403 error
- or the file contents via `readfile()`, after setting the correct Content-Type and Content-Lenght headers.

Comment: You call it like any other function - there's no "symfony" way to do it.

Comment: I mean, it writes straight to the output buffer, if you simply call it in action - then symfony wouldn't be able to properly output headers. Do i have to catch the output with ob_start() and pass it to $this->getResponse()->setContent() ?

Comment: Content-Type and Content-Length are headers, they shouldn't be affected by `readfile`

Comment: It turns out to be quite an issue using readfile (as per comments to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Is there a way to leave files in web directory and still be able to manage them?

Comment: Yes - you can use a .htaccess file to prevent direct access to the files. You will need an action anyway, to check the permissions.

Comment: @Maerlyn, can you expand on that in a separate answer?

Comment: I don't think it belongs to a different answer. However, you should try fpassthru() instead of readfile(). According to a comment on php.net, it had the same memory issue, but that should've been fixed in php5.

Comment: @Maerlyn, after I've checked permissions in my script, I still have to use php to initiate file transfer? I there a way to tell apache to simply return the bloody file (since it is in web directory)? I thought redirect to a file will do the trick, but redirect is caught by the very same .htaccess rule which results in an infinite loop.. )