# How to protect doc files?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I develop website where users can upload doc , pdf and text files . They also can see files list and delete files. Problem is in this files have personal data . Can i protect somhow this files ? I Want  administrators and moderators to see this files but also i want to protect from random  downlad from other peoples. I hope i explain well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them somewhere outside of the webroot, only accessible via your system. Whenever someone tries to access it, check his permissions and if they're okay, serve the file.

Comment: I found this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217815/secure-file-management-with-symfony . I can't understand the second part whit colling the file . Im steel very green and need more explenations.

Comment: Create an action that gets a parameter that identifies a file (like its id in the database). If that is an invalid id, respond with a 404. If it's valid, but the user can't access it, respond with a 403. If it's valid and the user can access it, set the Content-Type and Content-Length theaders and serve the file via `readfile`, for example.